# Use an SSIS parameter inside of an Execute Operation

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package with a parameter параметром $[Project::MyParam]. Inside the SSIS package I have  a component of  Execute Process Task type. The component has a row Arguments; this is where I want to put a value from $[Project::MyParam].
How should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use expressions to override the Arguments, right click on the execute task and the select properties or press F4, find the expression part and open it up, in there is a place for arguments

[image: Open Expressions]

Then create your expression for Arguments

[image: Set Arguments]

Expressions can be used to override nearly any input on any component, please see below docs for more information

[SSIS Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-ssis-expressions?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=An%20expression%20is%20a%20combination,referencing%20multiple%20columns%20and%20variables.)